# Identify duplicate photos in Photos (Catalina 10.15)?

Tags: photos, catalina, macos

I have an aging Photos library with 40000+ photos in it, and I would like to identify duplicates to remove them.

Previously this has not been possible without third-party software, but I noticed that the "Indexing library" message mentioned something about finding duplicates, I was wondering if it was possible now under MacOS 10.15 (Catalina).